# print all possible sub-strings in a given string without repetition of charactes

Tags: java, string

I found substring programs here which are printing only largest substrings.
but I am trying to code for printing all possible substrings in a given string,and among all those sub-strings largest sub-string also printed on console.so please any one can help me to do this without using String methods
I tried this program but I am getting string without repeating character below

```
public class SubSring {
     static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        static String str = sc.nextLine();

        public static void main(String[] args) {
           String store="";
            for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
                if (store.indexOf(str.charAt(i))<0) {
                    store = store+str.charAt(i);
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Result word " +store);

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you currently have there will loop through all of the characters in `str` and add them to `store` if they do not currently exist in the string. Therefore `store` will essentially be a copy of `str` with duplicates removed.

In order to get all of the possible substrings of `str` you will need to change `store` to be a collection of strings. A LinkedList might be an appropriate choice since you don't know how many substrings there will be and this will allow you to easily add any number of results.

So now you have a place to put your results you need to find all the possible substrings. To do this you will need two loops. One will determine the start position of your substring, the other will determine the end position. Everything between the indexes of these two loops will be a valid substring which you can add to your list of results.

So your main method should contain something like the following:

```
        List<String> store = new LinkedList<String>();
        for (int i=0; i< str.length(); i++) {
            String substring = String.valueOf(str.charAt(i));
            // This is a valid substring so add to results
            store.add(substring);
            // Loop through the rest of the characters in str adding each
            // character to the substring variable.
            for (int j=i+1; j<str.length(); j++) {
               if (substring.indexOf(str.charAt(j)) < 0) {
                  substring += str.charAt(j);
                  // Add each substring to list of results
                  store.add(substring);
               }
            }
        }
```

You can then loop through each of the strings in `store` and print them out.

In the real world you are likely to need the possible substrings stored in a collection for further processing, but if your requirement is to simply print out each possibility you can do this without a list like so:

```
           for (int i=0; i< str.length(); i++) {
                String substring = String.valueOf(str.charAt(i));
                // This is a valid substring so print to console
                System.out.println(substring);
                // Loop through the rest of the characters in str adding each
                // character to the substring variable.
                for (int j=i+1; j<str.length(); j++) {
                  if (substring.indexOf(str.charAt(j)) < 0) {
                    substring += str.charAt(j);
                    // Each of these is a valid substring so print to console
                    System.out.println(substring);
                  }
                }
            }
```

Comment: thank you sir for your solution.but without using list how to do this program

Comment: No problem, that is a question I thought you might ask. Rather than adding each substring to the list you can simply print it out if that is your requirement. I will update the code example to reflect this.

Comment: Apologies, my code did not reflect the repetition of characters requirement. Answer updated.

Comment: No problem at all. If you found the answer helpful please accept it so others can find the solution if they have the same problem. Thanks.